# How do I save extracted data into different files while looping through?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

the input txt file looks like this:

```
DATE ID ADDRESS
20161102 AB:2 xyzzzz
20161102 AB:2 fasafsdgs
20161102 AB:3 faasd
20161103 AB:3 fasfe
20161103 AB:4 ztwetwg
```

I want to extract data in separate txt files which have common ID.
eg: AB2_ID will contain data which are associated with only AB2 id.

ERROR:

```
File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1317, in savetxt
open(fname, 'wt').close()

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\\Extracted_files\\AB:2_ID.txt'
```

Code:

```
for i in data.ID:
    subsetData = data[data['ID'] == i]
    file_path = r'D:\Extracted_files\%s_ID.txt' %i
    np.savetxt(file_path , subsetData.values, fmt = '%s')
```

Comment: Does the folder `D:\\Extracted_files` exist?

Comment: yes it does in my D drive

Comment: Maybe try seeing if it will save it to the local folder first (i.e. just have the filename). That will help narrow down what's happening.

Comment: Windows file or directory names cannot contain `:` (among other characters). You need to change the ID string to avoid invalid characters (e.g. replace with `_` or something else).

Comment: Ok i have realized it that notepad doesnot accept ':' in a filename that is why it is saying invalid argument.

Thanks